# Setting up Vuetify in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm running Vue 2.6.10 and Vuetify 2.2.12 within my Rails application, but I'm having issues with getting Vuetify installed properly.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
[Vuetify] Multiple instances of Vue detected
Error: "Vuetify is not properly initialized, see https://vuetifyjs.com/getting-started/quick-start#bootstrapping-the-vuetify-object"
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.$vuetify is undefined"
```

Here is my dashboard.js file:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Dashboard from '../../assist/dashboard.vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)
Vue.use(VueResource)

Vue.use(Vuetify)

window.store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    organization: {},
  },
  mutations: {

  }
})

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')

  var element = document.querySelector("#assistdashboard")
  if (element != undefined) {

    const app = new Vue({
      el: element,
      store: window.store,
      template: "<Dashboard />",
      components: { Dashboard }
    })
  }
})
```

And my layout.vue file:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="dashboard-layout">
    ...
  </v-app>
</template>
```

I've tried adding `vuewtify: new Vuetify(vuetifyOptions)` within my Vue initialization in `dashboard.js` but that has not changed anything. I've also tried reinstalling both Vue and Vuetify to no avail as well.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if it has to do something with your problem, but you shouldn't check for `undefined` like that - `if (typeof element !== 'undefined') {}` is a better syntax.

Comment: maybe it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583771/9541423